# I'm making a discord bot that graphs lines, and every time i use the plot command more than once, it plots over the previous graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, discord.py

when i use the plot command, i expect it to sort the numbers and plot using matplotlib.pyplot, but instead i get this abomination
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/710208448326795404/710593242177208491/Picture69lmao.png 
This occurs because every time i run the plot command it plots over the previous graph, messing p the axes and everything. I want to know how you prevent this from happpening. Here's my code:

```
import discord
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def plot(self, ctx, xvals, yvals):
  xList = []
  yList = []
  for varx in xvals:
    xList.append(varx)
  for vary in yvals:
    yList.append(vary)
  xList.sort()
  yList.sort()
  x = np.array(xList)
  y = np.array(yList)
  arr = np.vstack((x, y))
  plt.plot(arr[0], arr[1])
  plt.title(f'{ctx.message.author}\'s Graph')
  plt.savefig(fname='plot')
  await ctx.send(file=discord.File('plot.png'))
  os.remove('plot.png')
```

I sorted the list so it won't mess up the axes, and I run the command like this:
`.plot "x values" "y values"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it to plot over the previous graph? If not, you need to clear the figure before plotting using the following:

```
plt.clf()
```

If you want to plot over the previous graph, but want the axes to be fixed, you can fix the axes using an axis object.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax))
ax.plot(x,y)
```

Here xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax can be determined by getting the min and max values of the data to be plotted.

Comment: Is it possible for an ax object to save file and clear? if so please show how. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Here's an example that does just that: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/misc/rasterization_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-rasterization-demo-py